# How do I get Litecoin prices with Coinbase Python API?

Tags: python, coinbase-api

```
client.get_spot_price(currency='EUR')
```

This line will give me the current Bitcoin price, but how do I find Litecoin and Etherum prices?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the correct `currency_pair` as seen in the [docs](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?python#get-spot-price)

```
client.get_spot_price(currency_pair='LTC-EUR')
```

**EDIT**

This seems to be a bug noted on [github](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python/issues/32). For a quick fix, you can modify the client.py file by chaning this function

```
def get_spot_price(self, **params):
    """https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-spot-price"""
    response = self._get('v2', 'prices','spot', data=params)
    return self._make_api_object(response, APIObject)
```

to this

```
def get_spot_price(self, **params):
    """https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-spot-price"""
    currency_pair = params['currency_pair']
    response = self._get('v2', 'prices', currency_pair,'spot', data=params)
    return self._make_api_object(response, APIObject)
```

Comment: I tried this but instead of getting the LTC price in EUR, I get BTC price in my local currency...

Comment: Also, I haven't tested this, but the last comment said it has been changed in the master on github, so possibly you could clone the master

Comment: `currency_pair = params['currency_pair']` will throw an error if `'currency_pair'` is not in the params. Also you don't want to send this in both the `URL` and the `data`, perhaps: `currency_pair = params.pop('currency_pair', 'BTC-USD')` would be better.

Comment: @AChampion, this was already a bug mentioned on the github link and a work around...

Comment: @djk47463 I saw that and have made a similar comment on the issue. Sending the `currency_pair` in both the `URL` and `params` is at a minimum redundant.